# Service class stopped in android 5.0.2

Tags: android, android-service, android-wake-lock, android-broadcastreceiver

I used a Service class in my application. It works fine at other versions, but when I tested it in 5.0.2, it works fine when the application is in running state. But when I closed my Application, the service is stopped. I need the service to run continuously in background.

Here is my Service class:

```
  public class ServiceClass extends Service{
  @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   UpdateLocation();
   return Service.START_STICKY;
   }
       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
       }

private void UpdateLocation() {

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

                    }

                    if (mLastLocation != null) {

                        Log.e("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
                        latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                        longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();


                    }
                    GetLocationUpdate();


                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
    }, 0, UPDATE_TASK);
  }

  }
```

This is my WakefulBroadcastReceiver

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override  
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

    Intent service = new Intent(context, ServiceClass.class);
    context.startService(service);   

 }  
}
```

My Manifest File

```
      <service android:name=".service.ServiceClass" />

    <receiver android:name=".service.BootCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Thanks in advance and please help me.

Comment: is there any error or exception coming when your service stopped?

Comment: thanks for the reply @Silvans no i didn't get the exception

Comment: What do you mean "I closed my application" ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I guess he meant he swiped it out from recent's list.

Comment: Well, we don't know what he meant. So let's not guess

Comment: yes when i closed the application the service is stop

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: this problem is only taking place at android 5.02

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for the reply u are correct when i closed my application the service is stop

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your question